# How to prevent textures from stretching?

Tags: materials, node-editor, procedural

I am trying to create a cartoon realistic pizza. However though, when trying to add materials, some of the smaller dimensioned faces seems to stretch it out.

Here is an example of the Pepperoni, and you can also see parts from the Pizza portion as well.
[image: My result]
You see here, where the faces are more compressed, it stretches out. I want it just like the top of the Pepperoni. The top is perfect to this cartoon realistic pizza. This also happens to the Pizza itself as well. I am trying a similar effect with the Pizza and again, will need it all fixed.

Here is a screenshot of the node editor. Nothing much to talk about here except for how it creates the current material.

[image: Node Editor snippet]

Here is the blend file I am working on so if you have a solution, you can test out your solution before sharing with the world.

[image]

I have tried looking everywhere on the internet, with similar problems. But the answers however don't help me.

Comment: Have you UV unwrapped both the pizza base and pepperoni objects? You'll also need to add Texture Coordinate nodes to both materials and plug the UV output into the Vector input of the Noise Texture for the Pepperoni and both Noise and Image texture nodes for the Pizza.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An implied coordinate system for the *Noise Texture* is *Generated*. It goes from 0 to 1 on each axis. Because your pizza is a flat object, the Z coordinate changes much faster than other coordinates as a result of that. Look what happens with the cube below, once I scale it and exit to Object Mode, so the *Generated* coordinate system is recalculated:

[image]

So the solution is to use an *Object* coordinate, and adjust scale:

[image]